# python reopen and write data to an existing file (file name is given by user's input previously)

Tags: python-3.x, io

I am using python Rasa stack. In one class (`ActionAgree`) for example from the code below, I use user's input (`ID`) as the txt file name. Then, the data will be written into this txt file.
In another class(`ActionTopic`), I want to open this file again and write some data into it. My question is how can I achieve this purpose?

Part of my codes:

```
class ActionAgree(FormAction):

    def name(self):
        return 'action_agree'

    def submit(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):

        #this is to get the student ID as his/her input       
        booking = agree_info.save(tracker.latest_message.get("text"))
   put channel: " + str(lic_log))
        ...
        ...
        ...
        #using user input to create a txt file
        indexFile_senderid = open(str(booking) + '.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8')
        indexFile_senderid.write('ActionAgree_' + 'student ID: ' + tracker.latest_message.get("text") + str('\n\n'))

        indexFile_senderid.close()
        return[]

 class ActionTopic(FormAction):
        def name(self):
        return 'action_topic'

        def submit(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
            ...
            ...
            return[]
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by myself. I found that I can use the slot value (user's input). So I just call that slot value in another class.